# Enabling MFA delete on S3 Bucket from CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-cloudformation, multi-factor-authentication

I know that the MFA delete on S3 Bucket can be enabled using AWS CLI or SDK, like it shown in [this example](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/0636920020202/blob/master/s3_mfa_delete.py).

But in case of CloudFormation template, if I want to enable MFA delete, I will have to invoke lambda with this code.

Is it possible somehow to enable the MFA delete for S3 Bucket directly from the CloudFormation template without invoking the specific lambda?

Comment: I think no way too but you can take a look at [CF Custom Resource Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe so. The current CloudFormation documentation on the [S3 Bucket VersioningConfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-versioningconfig.html) resource only provides for the Status property, whereas the [API documentation for PUT Bucket versioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTVersioningStatus.html) specifies the MfaDelete property.

Comment: Enabling the MFA delete itself requires use of an MFA token, so it's not the sort of thing that can be provisioned with CloudFormation.